# How to define an event to a .cs class that is returning a collection of labels?

Tags: c#

I have a method that is returning a collection of Labels although i am able to set an properties of label but i want to define the paint event of label so that i can draw the items there in some format.

```
 public List<Label> drawLabel()
        {
            lstLable = new List<Label>();
            foreach (cOrderItem item in currOrder.OrderItems)
            {
                _lbl = new Label();
                _lbl.Width = 200;// (int)CanvasWidth;
                _lbl.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
                _lbl.Text = item.ProductInfo.ProductDesc;
                _lbl.Height = 20;
                _lbl.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
                _lbl.Paint()////this is the event i want to define for drawign purpose.
                lstLable.Add(_lbl);

            }
            return lstLable;
        }
```

I am returning this collection to a form where i am taking each label and adding to a panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear if you mean winforms, wpf or webforms, but in winforms just use the [Control.Paint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx)-event as any other event:

```
public List<Label> drawLabel()
{
    lstLable = new List<Label>();
    foreach (cOrderItem item in currOrder.OrderItems)
    {
        _lbl = new Label();
        _lbl.Width = 200;// (int)CanvasWidth;
        _lbl.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
        _lbl.Text = item.ProductInfo.ProductDesc;
        _lbl.Height = 20;
        _lbl.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

        //this is the event i want to define for drawign purpose.
        _lbl.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(LblOnPaint);

        lstLable.Add(_lbl);

    }
    return lstLable;
}

// The Paint event method
private void LblOnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Example code:

    var label = (Label)sender;

    // Create a local version of the graphics object for the label.
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    // Draw a string on the label.
    g.DrawString(label.Text, new Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Blue, new Point(1, 1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to the [paint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) event of Label class

```
_lbl.Paint+=yourCustomPaintMethod;
```

Answer (score 1):

use ObservableCollection instead of List

You can also learn to use [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I would subclass the Label control and [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cksxshce%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the `OnPaint` Method.

Comment: Not getting? Would you please elaborate a little